# Longest common subsequence as a similarity measure between distributions?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-theory

LCS can be used as a similarity measure of words. For example, it can be used to compute the edit distance. Assume the two words $\textbf{X}=X_1 X_2 ... X_n$, $\textbf{Y}=Y_1 Y_2 ... Y_n$ are sampled from two distributions $p, q$ of a common alphabet. If $n$ is large enough, can LCS be used to estimate the similarity between $p,q$? That is, when $n\rightarrow\infty$, does the length of LCS approach to some formula that contains some distance between $p,q$?

---

update: Since Andreas Lenz has pointed that the exact value of the LCS length is unknown, a better question might be: can we use the known upper & lower bounds of the length of LCS of two random words generated by two distributions to bound the distance between the distributions?

Comment: I fear that no easy answer to this question might be known yet, as the seemingly easier and less general problem of finding the *expected value* of the length of the LCS between two uniform distributions is unknown to date, see [Chvátal-Sankoff constant](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chv%C3%A1tal%E2%80%93Sankoff_constants)

Comment: Thank you Andreas! The most relevant result I found is https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1559 (seems only uniform distribution case was studied...